# Error: consider defining a bean of type 'long' in your configuration. "AtomicLong" springboot greeting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Following spring tutorial, I built simple Greeting rest api, during build it failed with Error below

consider defining a bean of type 'long' in your configuration. "AtomicLong"
[image]

Greeting.java

```
package com.firstgood.restservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Greeting {

private final long id;
private final String content;

public Greeting(long id, String content) {
    this.id = id;
    this.content = content;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I just commented out following lines and it worked. Keep Greeting class ordinary class and it will work.

//import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

//import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

//@SpringBootApplication

Greeting.java

```
package com.firstgood.restservice;

//import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
//import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

//@SpringBootApplication
public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```